# Why does this scheduling function not work as expected?

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I'm writing a small application that verifies that a few web apps are healthy. To accomplish this, I wrote a simple `HealthCheck` abstract class that requires two functions, `is_healthy` and `on_fail`. Here is my code for registering two health checks:

```
import threading
import sched
import time


def register_health_check(checker, interval):
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    s.enter(interval, 1, _check, (s,checker,interval))
    t = threading.Thread(target=s.run, daemon=True)
    t.start()


def _check(sc, checker, interval):
    if checker.is_healthy():
        sc.enter(interval, 1, _check, (sc,checker,interval))
    else:
        checker.on_fail()
```

Then, to register a health check, I do this:

```
register_health_check(CheckMain('foo'), 1)
register_health_check(CheckMain('bar'), 5)
```

`CheckMain`'s `is_healthy` just prints `checking foo` or `checking bar` respectively. The output I expected is:

```
checking foo // 1 second
checking foo // 2 seconds
checking foo // 3 seconds
checking foo // 4 seconds
checking foo // 5 seconds
checking bar // also 5 seconds-ish
checking foo // 6 seconds
checking foo // etc.
...
```

The actual output is:

```
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking bar
checking foo
checking bar
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
checking foo
```

What's wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered, I've decided multithreading is too complicated for this task. All I really want to do is perform a bunch of checks when required. I've redesigned the module to look like this:

```
health_checks = []


def register_health_check(checker):
    health_checks.append(checker)


def _check_all(sc):
    for hc in health_checks:
        hc.time_passed += 1
        if hc.time_passed == hc.interval_secs:
            hc.reset()
            if not hc.is_healthy():
                hc.on_fail()
    sc.enter(1, 1, _check_all, (sc,))


def start():
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    s.enter(1, 1, _check_all, (s,))
    s.run()
```